# Restoring a Differential Backup with an SMO Restore object

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2000, smo, database-restore

I am trying to restore a database by first restoring a full backup and then restoring a differential backup by using the Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Restore class. The full backup is restored with the following code:

```
Restore myFullRestore = new Restore();
myFullRestore.Database = "DatabaseName";
myFullRestore.Action = RestoreActionType.Database;
myFullRestore.AddDevice(@"C:\BackupFile.bak", DeviceType.File);
myFullRestore.FileNumber = 1;
myFullRestore.SqlRestore(myServer); // myServer is an already-existing instance of Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server
```

After restoring the full backup (which completes successfully), my code for restoring the differential backup is as follows:

```
Restore myDiffRestore = new Restore();
myDiffRestore.Database = "DatabaseName";
myDiffRestore.Action = RestoreActionType.Database;
myDiffRestore.AddDevice(@"C:\BackupFile.bak", DeviceType.File);
myDiffRestore.FileNumber = 4; // file contains multiple backup sets, this is the index of the set I want to use
myDiffRestore.SqlRestore(myServer);
```

However, this code will throw a Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.FailedOperationException, with the message "Restore failed for server 'servername'". 
Do I need to explicitly state that I am restoring a differential backup, and if so, how do I go about doing this? Or is the problem less obvious than this? Any suggestions as to what I am doing wrong (or neglecting to do) would be greatly appreciated.

**Update**: Not sure if this was originally a typo or whether earlier versions had this form of the API, but for later versions this line

```
fullRestore.AddDevice(...);
```

should be

```
fullRestore.Devices.AddDevice(...)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a little bit more digging I figured this one out. In order for the differential backup restore to work, the full restore needs to be performed with NoRecovery set to true:

```
// before executing the SqlRestore command for myFullRestore...
myFullRestore.NoRecovery = true;
```

This specifies that another transaction log needs to be applied, which in this case is the differential backup. This page has some more information that I found useful:
http://doc.ddart.net/mssql/sql70/ra-rz_9.htm

Comment: Restoring with NoRecovery = true will leave the database in a "Restoring" state. To make it usable again use this command:

    RESTORE DATABASE <database name> WITH RECOVERY

Comment: Hello, Donut in the same way can you please tell me how to restore the Database Differential based on a particular given date.

Comment: @kalyan I'm not exactly sure what you're asking; do you have a set of differential backups and you wish to restore them **up to** a certain date? Or do you want to **start** at a given date and apply all subsequent differential backups? Or perhaps something else entirely -- could you clarify?